# Is it safe to run MySQL transactions with $wpdb in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-database

As far as I understand the global $wpdb object utilizes just a single MySQL connection under the hood (by default).
Because the object is global every other plugin/theme/whatever seems to be using this connection.

My question is: Is it safe to use MySQL transactions with that or could other plugins/WordPress itself interfere with my transaction(s)?

To visualize how that could look like:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');


$wpdb->query(...);
$wpdb->query(...);
// ... and so on

if ( $condition ) {
    $wpdb->query('COMMIT'); // commit all queries
} else {
    $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK'); // rollback everything
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is by nature single-threaded. Also, a transaction is limited to the scope of the connection it is created in.

If you write a PHP function that starts and commits a transaction without calling into another plugin, there is no way another plugin can interfere with your transaction. Other plugins could be invoked by WordPress before or after your function, but not during.

Other PHP requests running concurrently would have their own database connection (connections cannot be shared between PHP requests), and transactions cannot span multiple connections.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't even think of that.

Comment: This answer sounds incorrect to me. Sure a particular transaction exists within the context of a single SQL connection, However, the _entire_ point of transactions is for interactions between unrelated processes each with a separate DB connection; surely transactions from different DB connections interact within the MySQL server. Note that multiple PHP processes can run in parallel for the same website; this is the common case rather than something unusual.

Comment: @StephenWarren, What do you think is the purpose of a transaction in an application that has one client connection?

Comment: There are a number of uses, for example ensuring atomic updates (or lack of any update) in the face of problems such as crashes/exceptions in a script, etc. Note the WP doesn't have a single DB connection; there may be one per each separate web connection.

Comment: @StephenWarren, So in other words, there are uses of transactions besides interactions between unrelated processes. Would you agree?